# Must declare the scalar variable in SQL SERVER and C#

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a method here that passing sql string through code and gets the values. This is failing and I want to understand why by looking at the sql being passed through in sql explorer itself.

This is the whole method, as you can see its getting the '@' values from the 'new' object being created.

```
        var rowsUpdated = await this.repository.ExecuteAsync(
                @"merge into MyTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) as dst
                    using (select @id as M_id,  
                        @username as Username, 
                        @emailVerificaton as EmailVerification, 

                    ) as src on dst.M_id = src.M_id and dst.Username = src.Username
                when matched then 
                    update set dst.EmailVerification = src.EmailVerification,

                when not matched then
                    insert(M_id, Username, EmailVerification) 
                    values(src.M_id, src.Username, src.EmailVerification);", new
                {
                    id = id, //e.g 1
                    username = username, //e.g "dros"
                    emailVerificaton = emailVerificaton, //e.g true

                })
```

when I try to run this sql code:

```
                merge into MyTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) as dst
                    using (select @id as M_id,  
                        @username as Username, 
                        @emailVerificaton as EmailVerification, 

                    ) as src on dst.M_id = src.M_id and dst.Username = src.Username
                when matched then 
                    update set dst.EmailVerification = src.EmailVerification,

                when not matched then
                    insert(M_id, Username, EmailVerification) 
                    values(src.M_id, src.Username, src.EmailVerification)
```

I get this complaint:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@username".

not sure how to pass these variables in, everything I try results in a syntax error!

Comment: In SSMS, do `declare @id int = 1` (etc), just before that merge statement. Or even more basic (just for test) replace parameters with literal values

Comment: Extra commas `@emailVerificaton as EmailVerification,` and `update set dst.EmailVerification = src.EmailVerification,` otherwise looks correct, assuming you are using Dapper. And if you are trying to run it in SSMS you could just put `declare` statements just before containing values